# Plotting Number of Times Value Appears in Two Dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, scatter-plot

I have two sets of data. Each contains a column for the name of the molecule and a column for the number of times that molecule appears in the sample. I want to create a scatterplot with the number of times a molecule appears in dataset #1 on the x-axis and how many times it appears in dataset #2. If a molecule is in one dataset and not the other, it appears 0 times.

Example:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
name = c("A", "B", "D", "E")
count = c(10, 1, 30, 10)
)
dat2 <- data.frame(
name = c("A", "B", "C", "F")
count = c(1, 3, 50, 40)
)
```

Point #1 would be (10,1) corresponding to A, Point #2 would be (1,3), Point #3 would be (0,50) and so on. I don't want to label my points since my datasets contain tens of thousands of molecules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try joining the `data.frames`

```
full_join(dat1, dat2, by="name") %>% 
  mutate_all(function(xx) ifelse(is.na(xx), 0, xx)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(count.x, count.y)) +
  geom_point()
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You would need a `full_join()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Data
dat1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "D", "E"),
  count = c(10, 1, 30, 10)
)
dat2 <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "F"),
  count = c(1, 3, 50, 40)
)
#Code
dat1 %>% full_join(dat2 %>% rename(count2=count)) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=count,y=count2))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label=name),vjust=-0.5)
```

Output:

[image]